# How do you call a check procedure that checks "all" and "every" part?

Tags: word-request

Would it be called a "General check"? " A wholesome check" "Integral Check"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call it a **thorough check**. You can also call it an **in-depth check** as my antivirus says. Another software I have has a **detailed check**.

A **full check** or a **complete check** are also variants.

Answer (score 1):

I think that'd be called *a thorough check*.

Example:

> The police first have to conduct a **thorough** investigation of the crime before any particular suspects are named.